# Ensuring Data Populates in next available row - code in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to write code to enter in next available row a value of 1 when a checkbox is checked and value of 0 if unchecked.

```
Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
Set LastRow = Sheet9.Range("a70000").End(xlUp)
LastRow.Offset(1, 2).Value = 1
End If

If CheckBox2.Value = False Then
  LastRow.Offset(1, 2).Value = 0
End If
End Sub


Private Sub enterMDGfunction_Click()

Dim LastRow As Object

Set LastRow = Sheet9.Range("a70000").End(xlUp)




    Unload Me
    DataEntrySystemHomepage.Show
  End Sub
```

Currently it wont enter into next available row. After one entry the datasheet stops populating. Does it have to do with my unload form code?

Comment: Yes, Unload Me removes the form from memory and all processing within the form stops.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set LastRow = Sheet9.Range("a70000").End(xlUp)
LastRow.Offset(1, 2).Value = 1
```

This enters a value one row down from `LastRow`, in Col C, but because you never put anything new in Col A, the next time you get `LastRow` it will again return the same cell in ColA as previously.

Either put something in Col A, or perform the end(xlup) from Col C

With a bit of re-work it's simpler as:

```
Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()

    Sheet9.Range("C70000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
                                 IIf(CheckBox2.Value, 1, 0)

End Sub
```